# Needing to set spaces in a NULL stringbuilder value

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have a field that I am trying to set the length of 25 to by using StringBuilder and then populate it with string values in specific positions within that field.  However, when I get a print out of the values in that field the value looks like this:

```
 M&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;0&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;&#0;
```

Obviously I am needing to remove the "&#0" values from that field. Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
String b44 = toRequestIsoMessage.getString(B44_ADD_RESPONSE_DATA.bitId);
    if (b44 == null) {
        // ***** 20130604 MS - Told Ralph since that position 1 is space filled initially in the request to the CORE so that he can modify for the AVS. *****
        String avsValue = " ";
        try {
            StringBuilder revB44Value = new StringBuilder();
            revB44Value.setLength(25);
            revB44Value.insert(0, avsValue);
            if (decision.cidResponse.responseCode != null) {
                revB44Value.insert(1,  decision.cidResponse.responseCode);
            } else {
                revB44Value.insert(1,  " ");
            }
            if (decision.cvvResponse.responseCode != null) {
                revB44Value.insert(13, decision.cvvResponse.responseCode);                  
            } else {
                revB44Value.insert(13, " ");
            }
            String revB44 = revB44Value.toString();
            toRequestIsoMessage.setString(B44_ADD_RESPONSE_DATA.bitId, revB44Value.toString());
        } catch (InternalISOMsgException e) {
            LOGGER.info(FormatData.fullStackTrace(e));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `String.format` ?

Comment: or a simple `char[]` and `new String(charray)`.

Comment: No I have not considered either but I'll give both a try.  Thanks for the quick replies. Regards.